# How to convert individual .php page to .html extension using URL rewriting

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My .htaccess file code looks like

```
# -FrontPage-

<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews 
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).html$ car.php?urlname=$1


RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).html$ america-tour-packages.php?urlname=$1


RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This one is the individual page i have created in .php, and wanted to convert it's extension with .html using rewriting RULE but normal rule is not working, kindly suggest

```
>RewriteEngine on
>RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).html$ america-tour-packages.php?urlname=$1
```

Comment: I don't know, but I have a server at One.com and you can choose .html or .php, and both works for the same .php file

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php
```

when you will access test.html the system will look for: test.php

Comment: This one is not working, it still opening the .php page

Comment: remove all code from your .htaccess and write only these two line make sure your mod rewrite is enable and hit url like "domainname/test.html" it will internally redirected to "domainname/test.php". try this let me know if you find any issue because my side it is working.

Comment: Hi, yes it's working but only when we are putting it individually, as you can see in code car.php page is where all the code is written to generate a pages dynamically if we remove that car.php code from there it's stopped internal pages to open and generate. if we put both together then this  RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php     one is not working

Comment: I think you don't need to specify page name only two line is enough I have tested http://localhost/angular/test.html?id=123 and in test.php I got $_GET['id']; and also same for test2.html.Both are working fine

Comment: Hi Dear, car.php is not only the individual page this is the page which is creating multiple detailed listing page, via the code written inside, so it called dynamically to convert it's URL into .html,

Comment: My problem will be resolved if we have some code to do this specially for individual page .